# Birthday problem given the first birthday

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

The famous 'birthday problem' finds that it takes 23 people to have a 50% chance of **some** two people having the same birthday.

However, how does the question change if given that person 1's birthday is January 1st, how many people would it take to have 50% chance of another January 1st birthday?

I think that the second question would require more people because we are looking for a specific pair while the original is looking for any pair. But exactly how are the numbers affected?

Answer (score 3):

If you have $n$ people, number one has a birthday on the first day of the year and the remaining $n-1$ of their birthdays are independent and uniformly distributed across a 365 day year, then the chances that someone else also has a birthday on the first day of the year equals one less the chance that none of the other $n-1$ have a birthday on the first day of the year.

So, you want to figure out the smallest $n$ such that $1-(\frac{364}{365})^{n-1} \ge \frac{1}{2}$. This means we need $n \geq 1 + \frac{\ln \frac{1}{2}}{\ln \frac{364}{365}} \approx 253.65$, so we need $n = 254$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the number will be higher. In fact, it will be much higher.

Ignoring leap years, each person has a $1\over365$ chance of having a January 1 birthday, and a $364\over365$ chance of having some other birthday.

Given a group of $n$ people, the chance that none of them have a January 1 birthday, then, is $\frac{364}{365}^n$, so the chance that at least one has a January 1 birthday is $1-\frac{364}{365}^n$.

You asked how large $n$ must be to make this chance over $\frac12$, or equivalently how large $n$ must be to make $\frac{364}{365}^n < \frac12$.

Since $\frac{364}{365}^{252} = 0.5008\dots$, and $\frac{364}{365}^{253} = 0.4995\dots$, the minimum number of people to get a $50\%$ chance of a January 1 birthday is $253$.

Comment: You need $n-1$ in the exponent, the first person is on the first of Jan., so there are $n-1$ remaining. This will make the answer 254, not 253.